# How to put large numbers(more than 15 digits) in an excel file using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel and need to put a 50 digits number (`$cellData`) in a cell. I'm using PHPExcel and prefer to solve my problem with that, but I have no resistance to work with another library.

I first did this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->SetCellValue('A1', $cellDate);
```

But it changes the number representation to scientific notation. So I Change it to this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1')
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->SetCellValue('A1', $cellDate);
```

It had no effect. finally I did this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->setValueExplicit($cellDate, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

It solves my problem, but adds a single quote before my number which is undesirable. How can I have my whole number, with no change in representation and no additional character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that final solution works. I mean this one:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->setValueExplicit($cellDate, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

But, I was watching my final excel file in LibreOffice Calc and it shows a single quote. When I load my final excel file in Microsoft Office, there were no additional character.